# Issues installing Rootless Docker

Tags: linux, docker, systemd

I am attempting to install rootless docker on Almalinux 8.6. I am running the appropriate script after disabling rootless docker:

```
dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install
```

and I keep getting the following failure:

```
[INFO] systemd not detected, dockerd-rootless.sh needs to be started manually:
```

I have performed various actions based on answers provided in this exchange. I enabled lingering:

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger <my-username>
(if I do this without the sudo as most people instruct, I get the following:
 Could not enable linger: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files)
```

in order to use systemctl --user. I learned that lingering needed to be enabled in order to use it. Except that enabling does *not* seem to get it to work:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

this despite the fact that I see my username when I do an "ls /var/lib/systemd/linger" command.

I also set the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR as instructed:

```
 export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID
```

where $UID is my userID. This has changed nothing.

I need to somehow get systemd working properly so that I can install rootless docker. How to I do this???

Comment: Some sketchy ideas: to fix `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory` you might need a reboot or try to run the command with `systemd-run --machine=username@ --quiet --user --collect --pipe --wait docker ...` or get a new interactive shell `machinectl shell username@` or maybe `sudo machinectl shell username@`

Answer (score 0):

Try using Podman https://podman.io/

> What is Podman? Podman is a daemonless container engine for
> developing, managing, and running OCI Containers on your Linux System.
> Containers can either be run as root or in rootless mode.

Comment: I agree that Podman is a better choice than Docker but  Podman.  Podman might also experience problems as long as DBus is not running (error `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`). Some related information can be found in the Podman troubleshooting tip https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#30-podman-run-fails-with-erro0000-xdg_runtime_dir-directory-runuser0-is-not-owned-by-the-current-user-or-error-error-creating-tmpdir-mkdir-runuser1000-permission-denied

Comment: It doesn't matter about Podman, because I am already aware of it and have been for some time. I have chosen not to use it for a number of reasons, not least of which is that I cannot use it on all the distributions I am using. Docker, at this time, runs consistently on everything I am using. Someday, when I can spare the time, I will learn Podman and use it. Not today, however...